# How to enable dual booting option at boot screen?

Tags: rhel, grub, windows, dual-boot

I have two hard drives, 160GB and 500GB. On the 160GB I have installed RHEL 6 and on the 500GB, Windows 7. When I start, the hard drive which is set as primary is booting directly. I have set the 160GB as primary, so RHEL 6 boots. How do I set the dual booting option so that I can select which OS should boot?

And by default the booting time is set as 3 seconds. How to increase the time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically just need to edit your grub boot menu.

As root, or using sudo, edit `/boot/grub/menu.lst`

The first thing to do is change the timeout value to something more to your liking. `timeout=30`

Now you will want to enter an entry for your Windows hard drive. It should look something like this.

```
title Windows
    rootnoverify (hd0,0)
    chainloader +1
```

The tricky part is understanding how grub addresses the hard disks and partitions. The `(hd0,0)` means the first disk and first partition. Look at your existing grub entry for your existing Linux installation. If it is something like `(hd0,2)`, you can be reasonably confident your Windows disk is going to be `(hd1,0)`.

In the grub menu, `default=` refers to the menu entry that grub will default to on boot. The first entry will be `0`, the second would be `1` and so on. If you wanted to change your default boot choice, you could either change `default=` to the entry you want (such as `default=0`), or make that entry the first in the menu.

Comment: Thanks buddy. Its working. My existing grub entry was (hd0,1) so I changed the windows part to (hd1,0). and now I am able to see and boot directly